# Regex in Python to find the exact string

Tags: python, regex

Just started working with python and got stuck with a find and match.
Code is as below

```
for line in f:
        if c in line:
            catch = line.split(' ', 1)[1]
            return catch
    f.close()
```

so if my line has "TRA trace" and when I input TR, it returns the vale for TRA and not TR. Is there anything that can be done in the if condition to mach the exact input string. Thank you.

Comment: catch = line.split(' ', 1)[1] this will always give TRA

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
for line in f:
    catch = line.split(' ', 1)
    if c in catch:  # checks if one of the tokens is c
        return catch
    # Or 
    if c == catch[0]:  # checks if the first token is c
        return catch
```

Answer (score 0):

And for the Regex you can go for this.

```
import re
m=re.search('('+c+')',line)
if m.groups()
    return m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the exact input string
**EX:**

```
import re

def checkStr(word, line):
    result = re.search(r'\b'+ word + r'\b', line)
    if result:
        print "Found!"
        print result.group()
    else:
        print "No Match!!!"

word = 'TR'
line = "TRA trace"
checkStr(word, line)  #No Match!!!

word = 'TR'
line = "TR trace"
checkStr(word, line)  #Found! TR
```